# Error reading variable. Cannot create a lazy string with address

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    std::string s = "test";
};

class B {
public:
    std::vector<A> vec;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> vec;

    A a1 = A();
    A a2 = A();

    B b1 = B();
    b1.vec.push_back(a1);
    b1.vec.push_back(a2);

    vec.push_back(b1); // push_1 
    vec.push_back(b1);
}
```

Whenever I execute this app under debugger, and execution procecss reachs instruction with comment push_1, the execution process is stopped, and I have two followings informations in my debugger output:

> __lhs { s = "test" }
>
> __rhs { s = "error reading variable: Cannot create a lazy string with address 0x0, and a non zero length.}

The application exit code is 0.

But when I remove property s of class A, or repleace with for instance int property, this strange behaviour does not occure. Why it is happening? Why the string occurrance in the class A, causes this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce. What is your platform/compiler? BTW, for a [mcve] you are missing `#include <vector>` and `#include <string>`.

Comment: You're right I missed the headers. The platform is Linux Debian x64, and to compile I'm using g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516. The C++ standard version is 14.

Comment: Are you debugging an optimized build?

Comment: @bielu000 I too reckon that this is some kind of an optimized build. Tried this and couldn't reproduce. https://onlinegdb.com/S18rQTaUE. It's not the same architecture though...

Comment: I think that you're rightit could be because optimized builds, but I don't have any optimiziation flags set. It is really confusing me - I copied all files and directories of above app into another, new directory, and it works correctly... But the original source still works as I said above. I compared all files, from CmakeLists even to  IDE configuration settings, but there are any differents.

Comment: Your program runs to the end and returns with 0? So the messages are just info messages and no exception or error? Did you try to step into the `push_back`?

Comment: For what its worth I'm also seeing this.  I create an array of strings as a class member (i.e. std::string text[4] = {"blue", "green", "brown", "black"}; and index 0 is this error when I examine the memory.  Index 1 is green, 2 is brown, etc., oddly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is one and half year old, but today I did have the same problem. The same code work fine when compile in a project and do not work when compile in other project. Like you, I was declaring and initializing a string variable in the class declaration. My solution was add a constructor and initialize the variable in the constructor and not in the class declaration. I know its sounds weird, many many years using c++, but from now on I will always initialize the string variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I just ran into this question while trying to solve a similar problem. The thing wrong in the given code is the way the objects are instantiated:

`A a1 = A();` should be `A a1;`, etc.

My issue was from passing iterators from two different but similarly named containers to `std::inserter(someContainer1,someContainer2.end())`. Bad naming practice strikes again.